# Is it possible to use the value from enclosed SQL sub-query to be used as the the table name for its encompassing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Might be a bit of a strange request, but I'm trying to create a query in SQL that retrieves a value from one of three possible tables whose name, the choice of which is dynamically derived from the value of a field taken from the parent query.

So in theory

```
SELECT doc.[DOC ID], doc.[PO Number], doc.[Supplier Coder], doc.[APPROVER DEPT],
(SELECT [Approver] FROM {dat} WHERE {dat}.[DOC ID] == doc.[DOC ID])
FROM documents doc
```

where the table name {dat} would be a concatenation of the string "DEPT" and the value of doc.[APPROVER DEPT].  For example, if the record returned 1 for the APPROVER DEPT field, I would want to retrieve the value of the Approver field held in the DEPT1 where the doc IDs match.

Is this possible to achieve this in a single SQL statement?  I can incorporate the query into the existing C# code and provide a solution that way, however, the desired SQL statements are going to be used for views and may be subjected to editing from third parties, so I'd prefer to provide an SQL only solution if possible.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm using MS SQL Server.

Comment: I can't provide a reproducable example as I'm not sure to achieve the result myself.  I am just wondering if this is possible and how.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad database design. I suspect you're going to need to have a separate `SELECT` for each possible table and `UNION` them together.

Comment: You can achieve this with Dynamic SQL

Comment: Unfortuantely, the database design is a side effect of using OnBase and the need to extract data from a load balancing control table which references different keyword type numbers.  The values for each keyword type are stored in seperate tables whose names are either keyitem or keyxitem, postfixed with the relevent keyword type number.  So yes, it's a pretty awful system.

Comment: The short answer is no - you can't achieve this in a single SQL statement since it will require dynamic sql (not an option for a view) unless you want to use a limited and hardcoded approach as suggested by tek (along with the maintenance it requires when Dept values are added, modified, or deleted).

Answer (score 0):

While you shouldn't have three separate tables storing the same data, I'd recommend using a union if you can't change the schema to be normalized.

```
SELECT doc.[DOC ID], doc.[PO Number], doc.[Supplier Coder], doc.[APPROVER DEPT],
(select [Approver] from (
SELECT [Approver], 'DEPT1' as dept, [DOC ID] FROM DEPT1
union all
SELECT [Approver], 'DEPT2' as dept, [DOC ID] FROM DEPT2
union all
SELECT [Approver], 'DEPT3' as dept, [DOC ID] FROM DEPT3
) s where s.[DOC ID] = doc.[DOC ID] and s.dept = doc.[APPROVER DEPT]
)
    FROM documents doc
```